# Can I propagate a Jasminum sambac from an already growing plant?

Tags: containers, shrubs, propagation, vines

I already have a nicely flourishing [Jasminum sambac](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jasminum_sambac) outside my home. Its fragrance is so wonderful that I plan on growing it inside, near my room. Is there any way that I can grow it in a pot?

Answer (score 2):

Propagation is usually with semi ripe cuttings taken in summer - keep them misted and they should root very quickly. Alternatively, you could try layering - peg a couple of shoots down into the soil and wait, they should form roots, but it takes quite a while for this to happen usually, some months.

Once you've got roots, grow the plant on in an appropriately sized pot - pot up into larger pots as it grows, until it's in a large pot, maybe 15 - 20 gallons, indoors. You will need to provide support for it in it's pot, or it'll twine round itself and then collapse, becoming a trailer and not a climber.

To grow successfully indoors, you need to be living in Zone 8 or higher. They like hot and humid conditions during the day, with cool nights, and a sunny spot; they will grow in shadier conditions, but tend to be darker with fewer flowers. May reach 5 feet indoors.